# Setting api path depending on environment variable using Express and Angular on heroku

Tags: angularjs, express

The title pretty much covers what I'm trying to do, but I'll try to be more explicit.

In my main angular javascript file I want a string that defines the path to the server that my app is going to consume.  Depending on whether it is the production or staging app the path will be different:

```
var apiPath = [depends on environment, but a string will be here.];
```

I know that I can set the node_environment to production or staging in heroku, but where do I read that?  At the express level?  At the gulp level?  How do I pass those variables into my main angular js file?  I was thinking I could do something like:

```
export.modules = function() {
  return {apiPath: 'https://production.path'};
};
```

and have another export for staging, each of which would live in a js file that is either included or excluded depending on the environment, but how do I fire one and not the other?

I'm having a hard time finding a resource that gives a concrete example of this, and I'd like to follow best practices should they exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Heroku Environment Variables (that you set e.g. with heroku:config set) will apply to your node.js/express.js server, and will not carry over to your angular.js client-side code.

So, for example, you could do:

```
heroku config:set APIPATH=YourAppPath
```

Then, in your server-side code you could define:

```
var apiPath = process.env.APIPATH;
```

And you could happily use apiPath in your server code.

However, that does not address your problem, since you want to access apiPath in client-side code.

To do that, one way is to use [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) to bundle together your client modules (you will probably want to end up doing that anyway).

Then, in your webpack.config.js (which is just a node.js script), you can add something like the following:

```
var envVars = {           
     webpack.envVars.apiPath : JSON.stringify(process.env.APIPATH)
};


module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins : [
        ...
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(envVars)
    ]
}
```

You can then happily reference webpack.envVars.apiPath anywhere in your angular app. When you run webpack, references to webpack.envVars.apiPath will be replaced by whatever value node.js found in process.env.APIPATH.

The question then remains, when exactly to run webpath on Heroku? One option is to run it as a "postinstall" script, as described in the [Heroku article on node.js best practices](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices). So, in the "scripts" section of your package.json, you could add something like:

```
"postinstall": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.js --progress --colors"
```

Note however that the postinstall only runs when the slug is actually built, and not, for example, when you change the value of an environment variable.
If that is a problem for your app, you might want to consider having a different trigger for running webpack.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to me to set the path in express level for the server side, since most likely you are setting the port number and other variables in express anyway.
In express, you can have

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var apiPath = //depends on env
// serve routes based on the apiPath
app.use(apiPath + '/users', usersRoute);
```

For the angular side, I think it's best to use gulp + gulp-replace to replace the api path based on env
in your gulpfile.js

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var apiPath = //depends on env
var replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('task-replace-api-path-in-angular-js-file', function(){
  gulp.src(['src-path-of-your-angular-file'])
    .pipe(replace('API_PATH', 'apiPath'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build-path-of-your-angular-file'));
});
```

Comment: I ended up going with gulp-rename and defining multiple config files that overwrite a config file in source.  The takeaway for me is that their simply isn't a best practice, so choose something among the several common approaches that works best for you.